# Defining homomorphism in a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functions, group-homomorphism

The resource is present [here](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf), page 3. They define a function -

$F((w_{i}^{T} - w_{j}^{T}).w_{k}^{'}) = \dfrac{P_{ik}}{P_{jk}}$

where 
$P_{ik} = \dfrac{X_{ik}}{X_{k}}$, $X$ is a 2-D matrix, $w$ are row vectors of matrix $W$, and $w^{'}$ is row vector of matrix $W^{'}$.

Now they are stating that they need to interchange $w \leftrightarrow w^{'}$ and $X \leftrightarrow X^{T}$ to make the equation symmetric, and they use group homomorphism between $(R,+)$ and $(R_{>0}, x)$.

After which they state this as equation 4 -

$F((w_{i}^{T} - w_{j}^{T}).w_{k}^{'}) = \dfrac{F(w_{i}^{T}w_{k}^{'})}{F(w_{j}^{T}w_{k}^{'})}$

Questions -

1. Why are they specifically choosing addition and multiplication, and not other symbols? I can see addition but not multiplication.
2. How are they achieving equation 4 stated there? Since if they are using it over multiplication, then why aren't both the F's on the r.h.s should have been multiplied?

Comment: Where are the addition and multiplication symbils used that you are asking, the field operations?

Comment: Also I'm not sure you are asking this but variance is related to linear algebra which is an algebraic structure over fields, which is a group structures who's symbol is addition, with an additional group structure who's operation is called multiplication. If you do not have a thorough concept of this this paper is outside of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are asking is for $F$ to be a group homomorphism $(\Bbb R,+,0)\to (\Bbb R,\times,1) $. A consequence of this is that
\begin{align}F((w_i^T-w_j^T)\cdot w_k') & =F(w_i^T\cdot w_k'-w_j^T\cdot w_k')=F(w_i^T\cdot w_k'+(-w_j^T\cdot w_k'))\\ & =F(w_i^T\cdot w_k')\times F(-w_j^T\cdot w_k') = F(w_i^T\cdot w_k')\times F(w_j^T\cdot w_k')^{-1}\\ & = \dfrac{F(w_{i}^{T}w_{k}^{'})}{F(w_{j}^{T}w_{k}^{'})},\end{align}
since group homomorphisms preserve inverse, and $-w_j^T\cdot w_k'$ is the inverse of $w_j^T\cdot w_k'$ in $(\Bbb R,+,0)$. The multiplication is in some sort "hidden" in the division in R.H.S.

Comment: Can you just explain why is the negative sign has been taken as exponent in the next step? What I know from the identity of group homomorphism is that $F(u^{-1}) = F(u}^{-1}$. But I didn't find anything regarding that.

Comment: @phraniiac The identity you mention in your comment is what I mean by "group homomorphism preseve inverse". The point here is that when the group operation is given by addition, inverse are given by taking the opposite, since $(-x)+x=0=x+(-x)$ for all $x$. So in this case the identity becomes $F(-u)=F(u)^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation.